# Change form action URL using JavaScript from a HTML value

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I was making a uploader on Electron. As unfortunately, the framework doesent work with PHP, so JavaScript is the only way to function.

[I made a diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYyLd.jpg)

I tried using that code but didn't help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSubmitForm()
{
 if(document.pressed == 'submit')
{
 document.stash.action = "document.getElementByID("")[0].value";
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

and used this HTML Code

```
<form name="stash" action="Action URL">
```

Comment: should it be `document.stash.action` ?

Comment: I did changed it, but the data didnt go through. the code is on image along with the 'stash.action'.

but also `<button type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.pressed=submit" value="submit">Submit</button>`

and ` <form name="stash" action="" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">`

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById()`  and it should not have `[0]` as `id` would be unique on the page.

Comment: I did, it still didn't went through. according to the developer tools, it said `Redirected to file:///[path to electron]/electron/resources/app/index.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.zapier.com%2Fhooks%2Fcatch%2F457742%2Ft5knc1%2F&title=dssdsdd&file=&action=submit`

it was supposed to go to the URL from "webhook_URL" field. Unfortunately, because Electron DOES NOT support PHP, it's impossible to use cURL.

Comment: Looks like you have conflicting double-quotes: `"document ... ("")[0].value"`

Comment: I did even removing double quotes as well as the [0] but that didn't help.